# Changing the Scale and Fontsizing for Whole Application

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Our UX Lead Designer was designing things on a laptop notebook. So the person increased the pixel size to see things better. The software team followed instructions and now we have super large icons, tables, boxes, grids, cards, sliders, etc. Does modifying font size, eg: 75% and transform scale resolve all the problems generally in CSS, or is it not that simple? What actions can be taken to resolve this problem better? We have to zoom in around 20% Chrome and that resolves all the problems. Is there a way to conduct the exact same browser operation in CSS, without having the customer zoom in on Chrome?

Also, have you ever encountered anything like this, where a UX designer makes things on a laptop, and not realize, it will cause sizing issue?

Comment: how do you set the width of cards, icons etc etc?

Comment: we are currently using pixel size, starting to read comments below from Robin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We encounter this problem almost all the time. You should take everything in percentages/em/rem rather than pixels. Mac machines have more pixels than regular laptops. So in order to get the perfect visualisations of your designs(VDs) in all devices, you should always go for percentages and not pay attention to pixels mentioned in designs.

Comment: should UX specs also be designated in %/em/rem? Thanks

Comment: Not really. It is the job of UI Developer to consider the pixels and use his imagination and creativity to interpret those pixels in percentages and develop the webpages that will look like the VDs with **percentages**. Well, There is a case when client asks us to make a webpage pixel perfect. in that case, we need to have VDs for different devices and dimensions(Phones, Macbook, 780p laptops, 1080p laptops, IPad)

Comment: Let us take an example. If The VD size that UX has provided us is 2400*2000 px. In that case. every card which is 100px and there are 5 cards in a row. In that case, we should take every card's width as 19%(Leaving one percent for margin and padding as needed).margin will also be in percentage in that case. I hope that helps.